# How to refresh Static Resources after external stylesheet changes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've a static resource which I want to refresh after my Resource gets altered pro grammatically How do I do that?

I have full control over my XAML but I can't use Dynamic Resources.

Comment: `StaticResource` is resolved at compile-time. You can't change it at run-time.

Comment: What about a visitor which re-sets DPs by setting them to null and then back to the original StaticResource("...")? Sound like a lot of work but can you why it wouldn't work?

Comment: That's not how you do things in WPF. Use `DynamicResource` instead.

Comment: @HighCore I know that, I don't own some style so can't change them from static to dynamic - did you read the last part of the question?